# Next-redux-wrapper with next-redux-saga: store being created twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js, next-redux-wrapper

EDIT: It seems to be something with regards to the interaction between 'next-redux-saga' and the new version of 'redux-saga' -- I had patched 'next-redux-saga' locally so it would work with '1.0.0' but on reverting it and changing back to 'redux-saga' 0.16.0 the problem below has gone away.  I will investigate further

I'm connecting Next.js to redux to my react app using next-redux-wrapper and next-redux-saga.  It works inconsistently.  I did some debugging and found that my custom createStore function is being called twice: once when the app first boots, just before `getInitialProps` in `_app.js`,  and then again just after `pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps({ctx});` returns in `_app.js`.

I used the sample redux-saga code from the Next.js site -- Apart from the fact that there are a lot of other things going on in the project app that are not going on in the Next.js sample app, the largest difference is that the store provider surrounds a Layout component in _app.js and this in turn holds three components, one for the header, one for the footer and one for the main content -- each of these is connected with the store.

Here is a trace of what happens -- it's both my console.logs as well as next-redux-wrapper's debug statements.  When the data or props are received correctly I indicate that, although I don't print all the data below (it appears in the log).  You will see at the end of the log where the data is **not** received correctly.

Thanks for your help!

```
   creating store::::
1. WrappedApp.getInitialProps wrapper got the store with state { home: {} }
_app.js getInitialProps
calling Component.getInitialProps
index.js, getInitialProps isServer =  true
index.js, dispatching saga loadData inside index.js getInitialProps, isServer =  true
fetching data in saga from route home:  http://something.else.com/api/es/
returning Component.getInitialProps
storing data in store { name: 'Home',
  published: true,
  draft: false,
  layout_id: 1,}
3. WrappedApp.getInitialProps has store state { home:
   { data:... } // data received correctly
4. WrappedApp.render created new store with initialState { home:
     { data:... } // data received correctly
creating store::::
rendering _app.js, main render, props =  { Component:
   { [Function: Connect]
     WrappedComponent: { [Function: Index] propTypes: [Object] },
     displayName: 'Connect(Index)' },
  router:
   Router {
     onPopState: [Function],
     route: '/index',
     components: { '/_app': [Object] },
     events: EventEmitter { listeners: {} },
     pageLoader: undefined,
     prefetchQueue:
      PQueue {
        queue: [Queue],
        _pendingCount: 0,
        _concurrency: 2,
        _resolveEmpty: [Function] },
     ErrorComponent: undefined,
     pathname: '/index',
     query: {},
     asPath: '/',
     subscriptions: Set { _c: Set {} },
     componentLoadCancel: null,
     _beforePopState: [Function] },
  isServer: true,
  store:
   { dispatch: [Function],
     subscribe: [Function: subscribe],
     getState: [Function: getState],
     replaceReducer: [Function: replaceReducer],
     runSagaTask: [Function],
     sagaTask:
      { '@@redux-saga/TASK': true,
        id: 10,
        meta: [Object],
        isRoot: true,
        context: {},
        joiners: null,
        queue: [Object],
        cancel: [Function: cancel],
        cont: [Function],
        end: [Function: end],
        setContext: [Function: setContext],
        toPromise: [Function: toPromise],
        isRunning: [Function: isRunning],
        isCancelled: [Function: isCancelled],
        isAborted: [Function: isAborted],
        result: [Function: result],
        error: [Function: error] },
     [Symbol(observable)]: [Function: observable] } }
in header.js selector, state =  { home:
     { data:... } // data received correctly
rendering Header.js, props =  { headerData:...} // props received correctly
rendering index.js, props =  {...,} // props received correctly
rendering Footer.js, props =  {...,} // props received correctly
creating store::::
1. WrappedApp.getInitialProps wrapper got the store with state { home: {} }
_app.js getInitialProps
calling Component.getInitialProps
index.js, getInitialProps isServer =  true data =  undefined
index.js, dispatching loadData inside index.js getInitialProps, isServer =  true
returning Component.getInitialProps
3. WrappedApp.getInitialProps has store state { home: {} }
4. WrappedApp.render created new store with initialState { home: {} } // store is EMPTY
creating store::::
rendering _app.js, // props are NOT received correctly
```

Comment: Hey, this looks like exactly my problem. Did you end up figuring it?

Comment: @Guard -- it was a problem in the interaction between next-redux-saga and redux-saga.  A new version of one broke the old version of the other.  I don't know whether it was ever resolved but you can check their repos.  In the end the project went with Gatsby...